# Hide the sidebar links in newer versions of Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

While I'm uncertain of the precise names for them - I'm referring to these:

[image]

There is a strip of these on both the left and right sides. I simply want to "reclaim" the real estate (since I have the keyboard shortcuts memorized).

Oh I see they're also at the bottom..

[image]

Why is it that GUI designers want to continually cram more stuff on the screen.. at the expense of usable working /editing areas..

Comment: If you want to avoid all that, you can go to view --> Enter Distraction free mode, this will show only editor with code and nothing else, You can also untick view --> toolbar, toolbar button, status bar, navigation bar

Comment: That is not the layout desired: I do need the left navigation pane and the debugger. Just not the extra new stuff.

Comment: Unfortunately tool buttons are mapped with project navigation with other buttons in sidebar as you mentioned, but on removing all buttons from side bar might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it:  Under `_View | _Tool Buttons`

[image]

Dear `JetBrains`: thanks for making this configurable after all.

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/manipulating-the-tool-windows.html#show-all

Answer (score 2):

You could also click on the square icon on bottom left to toggle the Tool Buttons.

Comment: not finding that - please add a screenshot. Oh I see that's Intellij only  - pycharm does not even have that.

Answer (score 0):

I only wanted to hide the right sidebar, so after I dragged all icons to the left sidebar, the right sidebar automatically disappeared.

You could also right click on each icon and click "Hide" or "Move to" a different sidebar.